# How to forward a [sub]domain to another address? (not just HTTP!)

Tags: redirects, subdomain, http

I have bought domain1.me from GoDaddy... (yeah, I know... but ME domain registrars seemed quite hard to find...) I'm mainly hosted at 1and1. I have registered subdomain sub1.domain1.me and redirected it to my 1and1 account. That should eventually work fine. Then I have registered sub2.domain1.me and tried to redirect it to a box at home. It works #1 when for HTTP. I can access SSH server without any problem when I use the IP directly, but not when using sub2.domain1.me:22. The way I see this, they (GoDaddy) are redirecting only on port 80 (why would they?). I have looked at 1and1 forwarding too and they ask for an URI starting with http so I guess that's the same behavior.

What are you guys doing to be able to host stuff from home (HTTP, SSH, SVN, Git, etc. etc.) using a domain name to prevent everyone to have to remember your IP???

Heeeelp!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the why, it would depend on how they're redirecting.

If it's truly a HTTP Redirect then it can only redirect HTTP.

If they're doing port forwarding or an equivalent, they'd have to specify a port or port range to forward and it's generally considered more secure to limit it to specifically the ports you want.  I'm guessing the vast majority of people only need HTTP(S).  Maybe if you contact them they can make a special case for you.

If they're just pointing DNS records, it should just work as far as I know.

> What are you guys doing to be able to
>   host stuff from home (HTTP, SSH, SVN,
>   Git, etc. etc.) using a domain name to
>   prevent everyone to have to remember
>   your IP???

I generally don't.  I keep my source control and FTP etc with my hosting provider and that generally works well for me.

Before I had a hosting provider (aka back when I was a broke high school student) I used [No-IP](http://www.no-ip.com/services/managed_dns/free_dynamic_dns.html) to get a free subdomain pointing to my machine.  If you don't need to use your own domain (i.e. it's just your friends or something) then you could go that route.  They might have a paid solution that lets you use your own domain, but I haven't used any of their paid stuff, so I can't say for sure.

Comment: I guess it will be no-ip for now. It seems to work better than the "HTTP redirect"...

Answer (score 0):

I just point the dns for the hostname to my home ip address.  I have to repoint it when it changes - but that isn't very often.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm doing too... Can you SSH to your hostname? I can SSH using the IP directly, but it seems I'm not able to use other ports than 80/HTTP when using the domain name.

Comment: yes I can. 

I'd suggest checking the ssh config and firewall rules.  It sounds like something is configured weirdly on the box.

Comment: It works with direct IP and with some other redirection mechanisms (no-ip, for example).